# How to map separate sets of URL prefixes to Flask blueprints

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a Flask app that handles a range of URLs. I'm splitting it up into multiple handler modules, where the handler depends on the first element of the path. The mapping between path/URL prefixes and handlers is a bit like this:

- /one/... => Handler A
- /two/... => Handler A
- /three/... => Handler B
- /four/... => Handler B

Calling a given URL under /one/... gets you something very similar (though not identical) to the same URL under /two/ - hence the desire to use the same handler for both those sets of URLs. At the same time Handler A does something very different to Handler B, therefore the desire to implement a clear separation, with separate modules for each.

**Blueprints seem to be a great way to do this - and for the most part appear to work well. Where I'm struggling is in setting up differentiated behavior for /one/ vs /two/ (and /three/ vs /four/). In other words, exposing the actual URL prefix to the handler.**

As an example handler A looks like

```py
# handler_A.py

from flask import Blueprint

handler_A = Blueprint('handler_A', __name__)

@handler_A('/somepage', methods=['GET'])
def get_page():
    return "You've reached somepage provided to you by handler A"
```

And handler B has a similar structure (but does something very different).

Then the app looks like

```py
# app.py

from flask import Flask
from handler_A import handler_A
from handler_B import handler_B

app = Flask(__name__)

app.register_blueprint(handler_A, url_prefix='/one')
app.register_blueprint(handler_A, url_prefix='/two')
app.register_blueprint(handler_B, url_prefix='/three')
app.register_blueprint(handler_B, url_prefix='/four')
```

The part that I can't seem to do "nicely" is figuring out whether an endpoint within Handler A (for example) was called from a URL prefixed with /one/ or /two/. This is an important distinction for me, though as soon as the handler is called that information is obscured. I've looked through the docs but can't find a clean way to do this.

The following are the options I've thought of/attempted so far:

- Grabbing `request.path` from within the handler and pulling out the prefix from the string. This is simple and it works, but seems awkward
- Setting up a separate blueprint for each top-level path, and "merging" the execution flow from four blueprints into the two handlers I have
- Making the top-level of the URL be a parameter that's recorded in the context (like in https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/urlprocessors/#internationalized-blueprint-urls). However I think this also requires me to write a custom URL processor, if I want "one" and "two" to match one `url_prefix`, while "two" and "three" match another.

Is there smart way to do this that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3):

To me the `request.path` is a good solution. It's awkward in that it's an implicit parameter of the function; the only difference between this and the solution you're looking for is this explicit vs. implicit parameters. I think this method albeit imperfect is more readable than the complexities required to make this explicit.

If you want, you could extract the core function and pass it the results of the `request.path` s.t. it's more explicit.

```
@handler_A('/somepage', methods=['GET'])
def getPage():
    return pageForPath(request.path)

def pageForPath(path):
    return '<html> .... path ... </html>
```

Comment: Thanks @gbarnett! Looks like this will indeed be the way to do it.

Comment: should be request.path